# TypeError: Failed to fetch with Edge and Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, blazor

I have a WPA Blazor application with an ASP.NET MVC API for the back end.

I have a file import and upload process that can run quite long (20+ minutes).  I have set the `HTTPContext` to a timeout of 30 min (On Razor page).  But at about 4-5 min into the process I get the following error(text is from Microsoft Edge Developers Tools Console):

> Access to fetch at 'https://myapp.azurewebsites.net/fileupload?aimporttype=InsertProduction&ausername=' from origin 'https://myapp.azurewebsites.net' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I thought that addressed this problem in the following code:

This is the startup class for the API:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
                builder => builder
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowCredentials()
                    .SetIsOriginAllowed((host) => true)
                    .AllowAnyHeader());
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ProductionContext>(opt => opt.UseSqlServer(AppSettings.Instance.GetConnection("SQLAZURE_Connection")));
        
        services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        );

        services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(options =>
        {
            Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options);
            options.TokenValidationParameters.RoleClaimType = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role";
        },
        options => { Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options); });

        services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
        {
            c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "ProductionAPI", Version = "v1" });
        });

        services.AddControllers();

        AppSettings.Instance.SetConfiguration(Configuration);
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment() || env.IsProduction())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "ProductionAPI v1");
                c.RoutePrefix = "";     // Shows the SwaggerUI page
            });
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseRouting();
        app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
        });
    }
```

And my SubmitFileAsync call from the Client:

```
public async Task SubmitFileAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_selectionValue))
            {
                _importSelectionCheckVisible = true;
                return;
            }

            _uploadResult = "Uploading file...";

            var lContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            lContent.Add(
                content: _fileStream,
                name: "\"file\"",
                fileName: _selectedFileName);

            string lUri = settings.ApiUrl + $"fileupload?aimporttype={_selectionValue}&ausername={loginState.Username}";

            HttpResponseMessage lResponse = await http.PostAsync(lUri, lContent);
            if (lResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var lJsonString = lResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                ImportResults AImportResults =
                    System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ImportResults>(lJsonString.Result);

                _importVisibility = "visibility: visible";
                _importRowCount = AImportResults.ImportRowCount.ToString();
                _totalRowsAdded = AImportResults.TotalRowsAdded.ToString();
                _totalRowsSkipped = AImportResults.TotalRowsSkipped.ToString();
                _carriersCreated = AImportResults.CarriersCreated.ToString();
                _insuranceTypesCreated = AImportResults.InsuranceTypesCreated.ToString();
                _transactionTypesCreated = AImportResults.TransactionTypesCreated.ToString();
                _totalRecordsImported = AImportResults.TotalRecordsImported.ToString();
                _importSuccess = AImportResults.Success;
                _duplicateRecords = AImportResults.DuplicatesDetected.ToString();

                _uploadResult = "Upload Complete";
                StateHasChanged();
            }
            else
            {
                _uploadResult = $"Invalid file type and/or format. ";
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _uploadResult = "Select a CSV file to upload.";
            _error = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

So, it turns out this is actually a authorization token timeout issue - NOT a COR's issue.